# Find Records in Mongo DB with PHP where ID != X

Tags: php, mongodb

is it possible to find all records in an collection where the MongoID is not in
an provided array?

Something like this (?):

```
        $search = array(
            '_id'    => array('$ne' => $ids) 
            'readby' => array('$ne' => $userId) // works
        );
```

Iam using PHP with the Mongo Extension.

Comment: hope this help <?php

$cursor = $collection->find(array("awards" => array('$in' => array("gold", "copper"))));

?>   http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `$nin` instead of `$ne` with arrays. Something like:

```
$search = array(
    '_id' => array('$nin' => $ids),
    'readby' => array('$ne' => $userId)
);
```

should do what you want.

Comment: Thanks does the trick (important: the entries inside ids must be form type MongoId()!)

Comment: Right. They can be any type, but if you're matching against MongoId/ObjectId, you have to use that type.